# How to find the type of an Object and then work accordingly?

Tags: java, object

I have a method where i can pass any type of argument. My objective is to find that the argument passed is a number or not and then find the absolute value of the number. The object passed can be double, Integer, string, long, etc.

### Demo.java

```
public class Demo{
public Object abs(Object O){
       if(Number.class.isAssignableFrom(O.getClass())){

    // Check the type of the number and return the absolute value of the number

        }
       else
       {
             return -1
       }
  }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106336/how-do-i-find-out-what-type-each-object-is-in-a-arraylistobject should answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to find the exact type of the object, you can use a chain of `if-then-else`s, like this:

```
Class<? extends Object> cls = O.getClass();
if (cls == Integer.class) {
} else if (cls == String.class) {
} else if (cls == Long.class) {
} else if (cls == Double.class) {
} ...
```

However, this sounds like a poor design choice: consider using overloaded methods in place of a "catch all" method that takes `Object` to avoid this issue in the first place;

```
public Double abs(Double O){
   ...
}
public String abs(String O){
   ...
}
public Long abs(Long O){
   ...
}
public Integer abs(Integer O){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do an **insatnceof** test :

```
if(o insatnceof Integer) {
//abs(int)
}
else if(o instanceof Double){
//abs(double)
}
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `instanceof` operator instead.

```
if ( O instanceof Number ) {
  return Math.abs(((Number)O).doubleValue());
}
```

Your requirements are getting stretched - is it OK to cast to a `double`?

See [What is the difference between instanceof and Class.isAssignableFrom(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you're looking for here is probably `instanceof`

```
public Object abs(Object O){
   if(Number.class.isAssignableFrom(O.getClass()))
   {

       if(O instanceof Integer) {
            ....
       }
       else if(O instanceof Double) {
            ....
       }
       .....

   }
   else
   {
         return -1
   }
```

}