# How can I find if my ArrayList of int[] contains an int[]

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, int, contains

I have an `ArrayList` containing `int[]`.

Assuming `Arrays.equals(int[], (a value in the arrayList)) = true`

why when I do `arrayOfInts.contains(int[])` is this false?

I assume it is because of the same reason that `(int[] == (a value in the arrayList)) = false` but should I be getting this error?

Can I correct it somehow?

TL;DR: Can I use Arraylist.contains() for int[]

---

EDIT:

ANSWER (if anyone searches this in the future here's the comparison code I made as a solution):

```
private boolean arraylistContains(int[] comparison, ArrayList<int[]> arrayListToCompare){
    for(int[] values: arrayListToCompare){
        if (Arrays.equals(comparison, values)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some valid code samples, preferably those you are actually testing your code with? What is `int[]1` supposed to do?

Comment: Is it Java? Just wondering why the strange syntax...

Comment: Fixed the syntax. "int[]1" was meant to indicate that it was not just int[] but a value in int. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A list of arrays stores only the references to the arrays, not their content, therefore `contains()` is only able to say, if the list contains the exact reference to the array you input. It doesn't evaluate the contents of the array.

If you need to check, if the list contains an array with specific values, you will have to iterate over the list and use [Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29).

Comment: Just made a function for it. Thanks. Thought there might be an inbuilt method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot because

```
    int[] a = { 1,2,3 };
    int[] b = { 1,2,3 };
    List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    list.add(a);
    list.contains(b); // is false
```

**`a` is not equal `b`**, it means `a.equals(b)` will return `false`. Method `Collection.contans(Object)` is using `equals` to check if an abject is already in a collections. So if `a.equals(b)` is `false` you get that the array is not in the collection even if they looks the same.

There is an exception. If they are really the same object `contains` will return `true`. See below:

```
    int[] a = { 1,2,3 };
    List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    list.add(a);
    list.contains(a); // is true
```

Comment: Can you clarify this? Any new user who sees your post will not know what you're trying to say since they look the same.

Comment: Look at `java.util.AbstractCollection` method `contains`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, unfortunately. I would probably wrap the array in another object and put that in the list instead. Something like (totally untested):

```
public class IntArrayWrapper {
    private final int[] intArray;
    public IntArrayWrapper(int[] intArray) {
        this.intArray = intArray;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(intArray);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return other instanceof IntArrayWrapper && Arrays.equals(this.intArray, ((IntArrayWrapper) other).intArray);
    }
}
```

Then, if you decide in the future to replace your ArrayList with a HashSet, for example, it will be simple (and you might get some nice performance gains).

Answer (score 0):

REFER -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/106351/1897935

```
ArrayList<Object> list = ...;
for (Object o : list) {
        if (o.getClass().equals(Integer.TYPE)) {
            handleInt((int)o);
        }
        else if (o.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
            handleString((String)o);
        }
        ...
    }
```