# How to compare method with additional feature of comparing type?

Tags: java, comparator

I want to create a comparator with additional argument of type to add more priority to the property if object belongs to the particular type provided in argument. For example,

```
new Comparator<Person>(){ 
    @override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2, Person.Type type, float weight)
    {
        float score1 = p1.getScore();
        float score2 = p2.getScore();
        if(p1.getType==type)
            score1 = weight * score1;
        if(p2.getType==type)
            score2 = weight * score2;
        return Double.compare(score1,score2);
    }
}
```

I want to find a way to implement such behavior when an object is of particular type.

Comment: So what is the question it looks like you already checking for type.

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is-- is this code not working? It looks like it doesn't. In any case, This might be similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106336/how-do-i-find-out-what-type-each-object-is-in-a-arraylistobject

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `compare` method is no longer implementing `Comparator` because of the extra arguments.

To supply these values, pass those values in a constructor to this `Comparator` class.

```
public class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person>
{
    private Person.Type type;
    private float weight;
    public PersonComparator(Person.Type type, float weight) {
       this.type = type;
       this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

Then you can implement your `compare` method with the proper signature, and the method body will use the values you need.

```
public int compare(Person person1, Person person2)
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot modify the interface which is

```
public int compare(T, T);
```

So if you want to add weight and type I suggest you to add such things as fields of your comparator.

```
public class  YourComparator implements Comparator<Person> { 
    private Person.Type type;
    private float weight;

    public YourComparator(Person.Type type, float weight) {
       this.type = type;
       this.weight = weight;
    }

    @override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        float score1 = p1.getScore();
        float score2 = p2.getScore();
        if(p1.getType==this.type)
            score1 = this.weight * score1;
        if(p2.getType==this.type)
            score2 = this.weight * score2;
        return Double.compare(score1,score2);
    }
}
```

If you want to go with the anonymous class implementation, you can make those attributes final in the container method (or fields in the container object) and reference them directly.

```
final Person.Type type = Person.Type.SUPER_HEROE;
final float weight = 0.38f;

Comparator<Person> comparator = new Comparator<Person>() { 
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        float score1 = p1.getScore();
        float score2 = p2.getScore();
        if(p1.getType==type)
            score1 = weight * score1;
        if(p2.getType==type)
            score2 = weight * score2;
        return Double.compare(score1,score2);
    }
};
```