# How to get class instances of generic types in generic methods

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic method, how could I get the class of T?

```
class MyClass
{
    static <T> void foo(T t)
    {
        // how to get T.class
    }
}
```

t.getClass() gets the most derived class, but T could be a super class so it does not work in case of MyClass.<Collection>foo(new ArrayList()).

Comment: It's impossible. Read about type erasure. The best you can do is add another parameter `Class<T> clazz` to the method.

Comment: `T` is `Object` at compile time in this case, so `Object.class` does the trick. Otherwise, how about `t.getClass()`? P.S. don't let anyone tell you this has anything to do with erasure, it doesn't; you haven't defined any bounds for `T`.

Comment: ```T``` is the _weak_ type, however ```getClass()``` returns the class of the _strong_ type. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106336/how-do-i-find-out-what-type-each-object-is-in-a-arraylistobject)

Comment: @PaulBoddington erasure has nothing to do this this at all. `T` is `Object` because there are no bounds, so at compile time `T` becomes `Object`. At run time, then `t.getClass` gets the type of the variable passed in.

Comment: @BoristheSpider But if the OP does `MyClass.<CharSequence>foo("bar")`, he wants to be able to get `CharSequence.class` at runtime inside the method. This is impossible due to type erasure.

Comment: @PaulBoddington type erasure is an implementation detail. Generics in Java are present at runtime and [easily accessed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1901275/2071828). This issue is that `T` _does nothing_ here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep your signature it is not possible. However, there's a way to solve this by providing the type as a separate argument.

```
static <T> void foo(T t, Class<T> cls) {
   // use cls
}
```

Then instead of invoking

```
MyClass.<Collection> foo(new ArrayList());
```

you call

```
MyClass.foo(new ArrayList(), Collection.class);
```

Comment: I am from C++, where we use generics to infer types a lot. Sadly, it is not possible in Java.